# Flutter: What is the name of the concept? please tell me what to look for better understanding

Tags: flutter, dart, mvvm

```
class ApiResponse<T> {
  Status status;
  T? data;
  String? message;

  ApiResponse.initial(this.message) : status = Status.INITIAL; //i dont know what is happening here exactly. please explain.

  ApiResponse.loading(this.message) : status = Status.LOADING; //same

  ApiResponse.completed(this.data) : status = Status.COMPLETED; //same

  ApiResponse.error(this.message) : status = Status.ERROR; //same

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "Status : $status \n Message : $message \n Data : $data";
  }
}

enum Status { INITIAL, LOADING, COMPLETED, ERROR }
```

please check the comments. I commented what i dont understand. I am just trying to guess what is happening exactly. But i need to know better to start implementing it. Can anyone share videos or articles from where i can get a better understanding of this thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these are what are called [named constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors) they are most often used to set specific default values when building classes.

you could use your example as:

```dart
final apiResponse = ApiResponse<String>.initial("message");
```

this wil create a new instance of `ApiResponse` where `status` is equal to `Status.INITIAL`

Comment: I understood that part. What i don't understand how to use Status.INITIAL in the code? See i understand i am setting the values of Status to there enums. But as you said use the example. But i dont understand why binding it with Status enum.

Comment: I assume here an Enum is used because the API response status can have 4 possible states. the way you implement it is up to you, maybe you're working with a data stream and you can listen to it and build your UI according to the status. I can't really know what you're trying to do.

Comment: You are Right, I am listening for data stream. Can you clarify! Should I read more about state management? This type of implementation is only for UI code?

Comment: not per se but when a stream event fires you can use a switch statement to do specific actions depending on the status. like in a state management solution.